# EntityExistsException persisting a second entity with @MapsId while a sibling-class is in the persistence context

Tags: hibernate, joined-subclass

I've got a curious problem I can't really work out. It's this exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.mycompany.Employee#101]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1359) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
```

The exception is pretty clear that there's an object in the persistence context that prevents my `persist` from going through. The problem is: there's no `Employee` in the context at all (checked with a debugger)!

However, there's the `Talent` instance I want to update to *also* be an `Employee`. They are related like this:

A person:

```
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<PersonRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

has many roles:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PersonRole {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "personrolegen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "personrolegen", sequenceName = "person_role_id_seq")
    protected Long id;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    protected Person person;
}
```

and both `Talent` and `Employee` extend `PersonRole` (nothing special to see there).

The exception occurs when a person already is a talent and I construct an employee with a reference to an existing person and call

```
entityManager.persist(new Employee(person))
```

Now the @Id mapping in `PersonRole` doesn't look very sound, can somebody confirm that it's the problem causing the exception above? And how can I do better?

What I *wanted* to express is that each role has a person attached to it that uniquely identifies the **child** instance of the role. Looking at the Persistence Context it seems like Hibernate is using `PersonRole#person.id` as the `EntityKey`, which seems to cause the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing it all down helped answering the question myself:

I don't want @MapsId on `PersonRole#person`, since a role shouldn't be identified by the person alone. In fact, if the role *could* be identified by the person, it's just another property of the person and not a new role.

So my original mapping design was faulty. Leaving off the @MapsId makes the exception go away.